# How to see the details of a Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, request, response

I have this function in TypeScript, which is part of an Angular2 service

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]>
{
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I know the response is a json but I would like to see the raw response as a string just for learning purposes.

I tried to watch it in the Browser Debug but the return of the 'get' method is an Observable and I couldn't find any useful information in it:

[image]

Is there any way to convert the response to string or simply watch it in the browser debugger tools? I don't know if this matters but the response comes from a in memory web api from Angular 2.

Comment: You can inspect the http request and response in the `Network` tab of the developer tools. You have access to all of the request/response data, headers and what not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why Amit answer got downvoted. That's exactly what you should do.

1. In Firefox, open the Network Monitor with Ctrl + Shift + Q.
2. On the Toolbar, click on XHR to filter those requests.
3. Click on the request, searching for the URL of your endpoint in the File column
4. Click on the Response tab on the Network request details panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most (all??) browser dev tools have a "network" tab where you can see the requests and responses.